# Swift Mirror API - Which protocols an object conforms to

Tags: swift, reflection, mirror

Is there a Swift Mirror API call that can tell me what protocols an object conforms to, ie:

```
protocol ProtocolA {}
protocol ProtocolB {}
protocol ProtocolC {}

class User : A, C {}
```

Then if I had the following code, it would print out A & C

```
let u = User()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: u)
let protocols = mirror.whichProtocols() // Made up code
print(protocols) //A & C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible at all in Swift. Swift reflection is a very limited affair. If you are willing to bridge your class into ObjC, you can use the [ObjC Runtime functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/) to get what you want:

```
@objc protocol ProtocolA {}
@objc protocol ProtocolB {}
@objc protocol ProtocolC {}

class User : NSObject, ProtocolA, ProtocolC {}

var count: UInt32 = 0
let protocols = class_copyProtocolList(User.self, &count)

for i in 0..<Int(count) {
    let cname = protocol_getName(protocols[i])
    let name = String.fromCString(cname)

    print(name)
}
```

Each of your protocol must be prefixed with `@objc` and your class must inherit from `NSObject`.